# django) request.POST method gives me errror : querydict object is not callable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls, django-request

I'm trying to add social login to my django-rest-framework app, but I'm stuck on this problem and need some help.

Login Flow: Request code(GET) -> Response -> **Request token(POST)**(This part is where I'm stuck) -> Response

[API reference here](https://developers.kakao.com/docs/restapi/user-management)

So, after I log in to social account,(e.g. Facebook)click authorize my app button, I get access code like this :

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def kakao_login(request):
    # Extracting 'code' from received url
    my_code = request.GET["code"]
    request.session['my_code'] = my_code
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('kakao_auth_code'))
    # This makes me redirect to 'kakao_auth_code' url
```

After that, I should ask for `token`, using user_code I got from above.

According to the [API document](https://developers.kakao.com/docs/restapi/user-management), I should use `POST` method like this.

```
curl -v -X POST https://kauth.kakao.com/oauth/token \
 -d 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
 -d 'client_id={app_key}' \
 -d 'redirect_uri={redirect_uri}' \
 -d 'code={authorize_code}'
```

So I implemented my code like the following :

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def kakao_auth_code(request):
    my_code = request.session.get('my_code')
    try:
        del request.session['my_code']
    except KeyError:
        pass
    request.POST(grant_type = 'authorization_code', client_id = '428122a9ab5aa0e8    140ab61eb8dde36c', redirect_uri = 'accounts/kakao/login/callback/', code = my_code)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

But, I get this error at `request.POST(...)` line.

> 'QueryDict' object is not callable

I just don't know how to solve this issue at `request.POST()`. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `request.POST` is not callable., it implements `dict`., which has the values posted in endpoint or url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Third Party Library called [**`requests`**](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) to call API which resides outside of Django Project:

```
import requests

def kakao_auth_code(request):
   ...

   data = dict(grant_type = 'authorization_code', client_id = '428122a9ab5aa0e8    140ab61eb8dde36c', redirect_uri = 'accounts/kakao/login/callback/', code = my_code)
   response = requests.post('https://kauth.kakao.com/oauth/token', data=data)
   if response.status_code == 200:
      token = response.json().get('access_token')
```